# Nexus equivalent for web development

Tags: web, bower, nexus

I've been using Maven and Nexus for Java backend development for quite some time, with very good results.

With web development, I started using the "usual suspects": Bower, Yeoman, NPM, Grunt, ...

What is the best way to managed project dependencies? I'd love to install a Nexus equivalent that would allow me not to download the dependencies for each project.

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried that, but bower can do that.  You can host a private bower registry.

Here is some links you could be interrested with : 
http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2013/08/04/How-to-host-a-private-bower-registry/

https://github.com/bower/registry

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll check these links out, but they seem to be exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For your NPM needs you can continue to use Nexus, as NPM support is part of Nexus OSS and PRO and allows for proxying, hosting and grouping. Check out [the documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/npm.html) and [a video demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bifXQ-D6zk) for more information.